# Installing package control into sublime text 3 breaks it

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sublimetext3

I know that this is not a programming question. But it is stopping me programming.

I have installed Sublime Text 3. Now I am trying to install Package Control. My ultimate aim is to install the package which does syntax highlighting for CJSX files.

The problem is that when I install the Package Control manager this breaks Sublime Text 3. Specifically many menu items are missing. And the programme crashes. I keep going round in circles: install Sublime Text / it works / try to install Package Control (following both the console method or the manual method here: https://packagecontrol.io/installation) / Sublime Text breaks / uninstall - repeat.

It makes no difference how I install Sublime Text - manually with a tar file, using a .deb file, or using apt-get.

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/988 ?

Comment: That's it. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

Since a new version 3.1.0 of package control has been [released a few hours ago](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/releases/tag/3.1.0), it could be a bug related to this version. I suggest you to post your bug on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Just visit this [Link](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) and execute the python code by opening command prompt

`Ctrl`+` for opening the command prompt, Both versions of Sublime Text(2/3) are provided there.